# How to overwrite values loaded from properties file if new value is provided in command line

Tags: java, command-line, properties

Funny enough there are 2 almost identical questions with a similar title that I found:

[Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15468625/1119381)

[Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15469504/1119381)

however my case seems to be slightly different.

So I have a `config.properties` file that is being loaded by `ConfigurationGetter` class like this:

```
public class ConfigurationGetter {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    public Properties getPropValues() throws IOException {

        try {
            String fileName = "config.properties";

            inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);

            if (inputStream != null) {
                prop.load(inputStream);
            } else {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + fileName + "' not found in the classpath");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
        } finally {
            inputStream.close();
        }

        return prop;

    }
```

Then I instantiate this class in another class like this:

```
ConfigurationGetter config = new ConfigurationGetter();
props = config.getPropValues();
```

And then I can extract the properties by key like this:

```
props.getProperty("keyName")
```

Whet I want to do is to overwrite this value I get from properties file if I provide it via command line. For example, if I have a line like this in my `config.properties` that I loaded as explained above:

```
keyName=true
```

and I also run the code like this:

```
mvn test -DkeyName=false
```

then `false` will be the one resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After loading the properties file, I do the following:

```
for (String propertyName : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
    String systemPropertyValue = System.getProperty(propertyName);

    if (systemPropertyValue != null) {
        properties.setProperty(propertyName, systemPropertyValue);
    }
}
```

This gives you the behavior you want by overriding the value from the property file with the corresponding system property value if it is present.

Comment: Thanks! It does what I needed. Would you say that this is generally a good approach for working with properties? I mean load them from a file and then apply your solution to find if any of them should be overwritten?

Comment: As long as you only have to initialize them once, I can't really think of a more elegant approach. If system properties can be changed at runtime, you'd have to check every time you get a property to see whether or not a corresponding system property is present. I've never encountered this case though. Applications and frameworks seem to rely on the fact that system properties are immutable after startup.